# System Load indicator not working properly

Tags: 22.04

Ubuntu 22.04
System Load Indicator

After installing and showing on Top Bar the small windows don’t open just green thin line and keeps flickering.
I had these application working properly in Ubuntu 20.04,
Can some one help to correct this.
Thank you

Comment: Please explain what you are asking. I can make no sense of that first sentence.

Comment: I install this application has two names the other is  indicator-multiload and it shows on the Top Bar of Ubuntu with early versions it work properly with ver.22.04 I have the problem I indicate above.

Comment: I too have the same problem.

Comment: did you solve this problem? if so, please let us know how